# Little confused about taking transformation

Tags: plotting, functions

I have a function f, the value of the function at x=0 is zero and at x=2 it is one. I am trying to interchange this, meaning at x=0, f should take the value of one and at x=2 f should be zero. Essentially I am trying to reflect my function. I am trying this. y=f(-x) to reflect about y-axis. What is the appropriate sign change I have to do to achieve this?

```
f = Sin[(((2*0 + 1)*π*(-x))/(2*2))];
Plot[f, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: So, `Cos[Pi*x/4]`?

Comment: humm. May be I am missing something. Why would `at x=2 f should be zero` when f(-x)? Do you want to reflect across y-axis ?  `f(-x)` reflect around y-axis. Not x-axis. So I deleted my answer, because I am confused what you are asking now.

Comment: I wanted to reflect about y -axis

Comment: @Nasser Actually the answer that you suggest works for me .

Comment: Ok. I undeleted my answer. I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

> y=f(-x) to reflect about y-axis

It would be better to make your `f` a function, something like

```
f[x_] := Sin[(((2*0 + 1)* Pi *(-x))/(2*2))];
Plot[{f[x], f[-x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

ps. why do you have `2*0` in there?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To answer comment:

```
ClearAll[f, x];
f[x_] := Table[Sin[(((2*i + 1)*Pi*(-x))/(2*2))], {i, 0, 2}];
p1 = Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> "f(x)", ImageSize -> 400];
p2 = Plot[Evaluate@f[-x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> "f(-x)", ImageSize -> 400];
Grid[{{p1, p2}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `f[x_] := Table[Sin[(((2*i + 1)*Pi*(-x))/(2*2))], {i, 0, 2}];` Actually I wanted to generate multiple like this, How to do this, using table function

Comment: @acoustics I've added for table.